Can I grant access to another AWS account only through Identity and trust policy
I have an AWS account A from which I want to grant access to another AWS account B, I have created a role in my account A giving the identity access to my bucket in account A, here's the role identity policy created in account A below;
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::connect-to-other-acct/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::connect-to-other-acct"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

I also created trust policy (automatically created by AWS) assigned to the role, allowing my second account B to assume the role, here's it below.
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account B ID>:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {}
        }
    ]
}

I know it's wrong practice to use root AWS account but I wanted to quickly try out this process because I don't want to create a role in the second account, so I tried to access the bucket using the bucket linked as accessible from my first account A, I logged in my second account B on a new Window and tried accessing the bucket from its link, I got a response that my second account does not have the permission to access the bucket i.e. list the bucket or objects even when I tried using s3:* as the action on the role.
I initially asked some of the LLM chatbot if I can do this without assigning a bucket policy to allow cross account access, but I got a response that I must use a bucket policy, but I later saw an AWS document that says I don't need a bucket policy to do this, https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3
Currently it is still not working, can I do this and if I can, what is wrong with my policy and how can I modify it so it works?

I tried to list the objects from my second account B but got a response that my second account does not have permission to list the bucket, I have granted account B permission to assume a role permitted to access the bucket from my account A.

How are you using credentials from Account B to access the bucket in Account A? Are you calling AssumeRole()?

I am not calling AssumeRole(), I thought that by defining the trust policy above in account A, my AWS account B root account would immediately be able to assume the role without any other intervention. How can I call AssumeRole()?

You will need to use the AWS CLI or an AWS SDK (eg Python) to call AssumeRole and receive the temporary credentials.

It appears your situation is:

A bucket Bucket-A in Account-A
An IAM Role Role-A in Account-A that trusts Account-B
You wish to access the bucket from Account-B

To do so, you should do the following:

Call AssumeRole() on Role-A using credentials from Account-B. These credentials will either need to be root credentials, or IAM credentials that have been given permission to call AssumeRole() on Role-A.
The call to AssumeRole() will return a new set of temporary credentials
Use those temporary credentials to call S3 APIs that operate on Bucket-A

